# Позиционирование изображения по центру

Tags: html, css, frontend

Как сделать чтобы картинка оставалась одного размера, а когда меняется размер контейнера в котором она находится чтобы обрезалась картинка не внизу и слева, а одинаково со всех сторон?

Comment: Покажите код. Вы используете bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример с фоном, свойство **background-size: cover;**

```css
.backgroundSize {
    width: 60vh;
    height: 40vh;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background: url('https://l2banners.ru/img/video_prew/orbis.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundSize"></div>
```

Тоже самое но с тегом img, свойство **object-fit: cover;**

```css
.objectFit__img {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: 50% 50%;
     object-position: 50% 50%;
  width: 60vh;
  height: 40vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="objectFit">
  <img src="https://l2banners.ru/img/video_prew/orbis.jpg" class="objectFit__img">
</div>
```

Пример без изменения размера самой картинки, только центрирование и обрезка со всех сторон которые не помещаются:

```css
.backgroundSize {
    width: 60vh;
    height: 40vh;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background: url('https://l2banners.ru/img/video_prew/orbis.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundSize"></div>
```

Тоже самое с тегом img (одна из возможных реализаций):

```css
.object {
  width: 60vh;
  height: 40vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.object__img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="object">
  <img src="https://l2banners.ru/img/video_prew/orbis.jpg" class="object__img">
</div>
```